# How do you do SQL Like operator in mongoDB using the official C# driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, sql-like

How do you do the following SQL query in mongodb using the official c# Driver?

```
Select * from tblUser where FirstName Like '%as%'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out how to do this.  You have to use Query.Matches

```
var query = Query.Matches("FirstName", ".*as.*");
```

Comment: you would be better off using "as" rather than ".*as.*". They are equivalent in MongoDB Regex queries.

Answer (score 0):

For the c# driver 2.1 (MongoDB 3.0)

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("<<name of the collection>>");

var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Regex("name", new BsonRegularExpression("Joe"));

var result = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

For the c# driver 2.2 (MongoDB 3.0)

```
var filter = new BsonDocument { { parameterName, new BsonDocument { { "$regex", value }, { "$options", "i"} } } }

var result = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```