# MongoDB text search on string array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, norm

I have the following class:

```
public class Movie
{
    string Name get; set;
    string Director get;  set;
    IList<String> Tags get; set;
}
```

How I can query the Tags? I want to query as SQL with a `like %term%`. I tried with `/term/i`, but it does not work.

```
term = string.Format(@"/{0}/i", term);
var tags = db.GetCollection().Find( 
    new { Tags = term  }, 
    new { Tags = OrderBy.Descending },
    new { Tags = 1}, 8, 0).ToList();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add your code that is using the regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct query is:

```
 var tags = db.GetCollection().Find( 
 new { Tags = Q.Matches(string.Format(@".*{0}.*", term))},
 new { Tags = OrderBy.Descending }, new { Tags = 1}, 8, 0).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following question.

[How do you do SQL Like operator in mongoDB using the official C# driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709644/how-do-you-do-sql-like-operator-in-mongodb-using-the-official-c-driver)

Comment: oops, I think you're using norm so the above is not applied.  my bad.

Comment: No problem you give me a Hint! Thanks! the correct was: db.GetCollection().Find( new { Ta = Q.Matches(string.Format(@".*{0}.*", term))  }, 
    new { Ta = OrderBy.Descending }, new { Ta = 1}, 8, 0).ToList();

Comment: You should update your question with the answer or submit an answer with what worked.  It will be easier for others with the same problem to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Better still, you can use a Regex in the NORM LINQ provider (reference http://schotime.net/blog/index.php/2010/04/29/nosql-norm-mongodb-and-regular-expressions).

```
_provider.GetCollection<T>().AsQueryable()
  .Where(t =>
    Regex.IsMatch(t.Tags, String.Format(".*{0}.*", term), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
 .OrderByDescending();
```